# Matched and unmatched uncertainties

Tags: control-engineering, control-theory

In control theory, according to the definition of matched uncertainty, the uncertainty enters the system through the same channel as the control.

If we consider the system:
$$\dot x = F(x)+G(x)u+Δ(x, t),$$

where $F$ and $G$ are known functions comprising the nominal system and $Δ$ is an uncertain function known only to lie within some bounds. For example, we may know a function $ρ(x)$ so that $| Δ(x, t) |≤ ρ(x)$.

If we require that the uncertainty $Δ$ is of the form:
$$Δ(x, t) = G(x) · \barΔ(x, t)$$

for some uncertain function $\barΔ$, this form is called the matching condition because it allows the system to be written as:
$$\dot x = F(x)+G(x)[u+ \barΔ(x, t)]$$

where now the uncertainty $\barΔ$ is matched with the control $u$, that is, it enters the system through the same channel as the control.

What are the physical examples for matched and unmatched uncertainties?

*(Levine, William S., ed. The control handbook. CRC press, 1996.)*

Answer (score 1):

One answer can be:

> Magnetic suspension systems, in general, suffer from two principal
>   components of uncertainty. The first of these are the parameter
>   variations, where the electromagnetic coil characteristics change due
>   to resistance heating, and the coefficients of the – curve drift with
>   temperature. The second important source of uncertainty is the
>   external interaction forces on the suspended body, which are typically
>   unknown. Robustness to parameter variations relaxes the accuracy
>   constraints on the force–current–airgap characterization of the
>   electromagnets, while resistance to external forces determines the
>   dynamic stiffness of the suspension. If the dynamical equations for
>   the voltage–current characteristics of the power supply are not
>   modeled in the suspension equations, then the parameter variations and
>   the external disturbance force terms appear in the same level of
>   differentiation as the system input, which happens to be the coil
>   current in this case. Uncertainties that occur in the same order of
>   differentiation as the control inputs are termed as matched
>   uncertainties.
>
> ...
>
> The matching conditions are typically restrictive for arbitrary
>   nonlinear systems and, if the voltage–current dynamics of the power
>   supply are modeled in the suspension equations, then the uncertainty
>   terms appear in levels of differentiation other than that of the
>   voltage input to the system and are, therefore, termed as unmatched
>   uncertainties. Modeling of the voltage– current characteristics and
>   consequent compensation of the resulting unmatched uncertainties is
>   essential to an efficient and cost-effective design of the magnetic
>   suspension system. By ignoring the dynamics of the voltage–current
>   characteristics, the controller may demand arbitrarily high current
>   slewing rates which, in turn, lead to an oversized power supply
>   system. Therefore, compensation of unmatched uncertainties in
>   nonlinear control system design is an important step in the context of
>   magnetic suspension systems.

*Mittal, Samir, and Chia-Hsiang Menq. "Precision motion control of a magnetic suspension actuator using a robust nonlinear compensation scheme." Mechatronics, IEEE/ASME Transactions on 2.4 (1997): 268-280.*